# Populate data from mysql to ejs

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, ejs

[Link to github https://github.com/AEkman/Quiz](https://github.com/AEkman/Quiz)

I'm trying to get data from mysql database and print to a html table using EJS.

This is my function call from database.js:

```
    this.getUsers = function (res) {
    connection.acquire(function (err, con) {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM user', function (err, rows, result) {
            con.release();
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
                console.log(obj);
            }
        });
    });
};
};
```

This is my route in app.js

```
app.get('/settings', function(req, res) {
var obj = databaseFunctions.getUsers(res);
res.render('settings', {
    obj:obj,
    title: 'Settings',
    classname: 'settings'
});
});
```

This is my EJS code:

```
<% print.forEach(function(users) { %>
<tr>
    <td><%= users.mail %></td>
    <td><%= users.name %></td>
    <td><%= users.password %></td>
    <td><%= users.groups %></td>
    <td><%= users.accountLevel %></td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
```

If i console.log(obj) i get:

```
[ { mail: 'info@andreasekman.com',
name: 'test',
password: '1234',
groups: 'java2',
accountLevel: 'User' },
{ mail: 'xtironman@hotmail.com',
name: 'ace',
password: 'ace',
groups: 'java2',
accountLevel: 'User' } ]
```

When i try to run /settings i get the following:

```
    TypeError: C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\views\settings.ejs:15
   13|         <h1>Settings</h1> 
   14|         <% include partials/template/createuser.ejs %> 
>> 15|         <% include partials/template/viewusers.ejs %> 
   16|     </div><!-- row --> 
   17|     <div class="content"></div> 
   18|     <% include partials/template/footer.ejs %> 

esc is not a function
   at rethrow (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:285:18)
   at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:85:9)
   at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:87:10)
   at returnedFn (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:555:17)
   at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:203:34)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:412:10)
   at View.render (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\GitHub\Quiz\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:960:7)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Node js is purely async, you have to write every result access inside a callbacks, in your case , database access call will return res , but you are not using that as object , use callback there

Comment: That doesn't work for me, the only data i recieve is "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the query inside the route instead, not pretty but did the job!

```
app.get('/settings', function(req, res) {
    connection.acquire(function (err, con) {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM user', function (err, rows) {
            con.release();
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
                res.render('settings', {
                    obj:obj,
                    title: 'Settings',
                    classname: 'settings'
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem atleast, after fetching the data and saving it to a variable the data goes away after the if statement is run. So i need to figure out how to pass the variable.

Any suggestions?